# Executing Symfony Composer Update in Docker-Compose Results in Cache Error

Tags: symfony, docker, composer-php, docker-compose, docker-container

I'm using docker containers for my Symfony project.
I already updated my composer.json, and I tried to download new vendors by executing this:

```
user@pc1:~/workspace/project$ docker-compose run -u 1000 --rm --no-deps composer update
Cannot create cache directory /composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Cannot create cache directory /composer/cache/repo/github.com/delphiki/BazingaJsTranslationBundle/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/delphiki/BazingaJsTranslationBundle, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+ff31a67c2b28+2017-04-06+0645
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden): 
Token stored successfully.


  [RuntimeException]                                            
  /composer/cache/vcs does not exist and could not be created.  


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sad you never got a timely response :( Did you ever solve it? I'm running into the same issue and I think it's because the /composer folder in the container has root permissions but you are passing the option to run as UID 1000. My guess is that you'll need to write a Dockerfile to extend the composer image and set the permissions you need.

Comment: @DinoAmino I have made a workaround instead. Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround for this was to just edit my docker-compose.yml
by mapping a composer directory from my home dir to docker

```
composer:
build: docker/composer
volumes:
    - .:/app
    - /home/user/composer/:/composer
    - ./docker/composer/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Comment: Nice! I did `touch .composer/.gitkeep` in my repo and then added `.composer/*` and `!.composer/.gitkeep` to .gitignore